# Use Google DriveApp to search for OR return a file's label

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the Google DriveApp to search files (e.g. DriveApp.searchFiles()) for a label value (e.g. "Content scheduled for deletion").

Looking through the documentation, I cannot find a way to do this.

Might anyone know if this is possible?

Here is what I am using as the base of my function, nearly all from: https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2021/07/search-google-drive-for-owned-files.html

```
    function searchDrive() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Search');
    var searchPhrase = Sheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchPhrase);

    var fileData = [];

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      // get owner
      try{var owner = file.getOwner().getName()
      }catch(e){Logger.log("Owner not Found")}

      // get file
      var file = files.next();

      // get file name
      var fileName = file.getName();

      var rowData = [fileName];

      fileData.push(rowData);
    }}
```

This works fine but I would like to add search for OR return a file's label.  For example, Label = 'Content scheduled for deletion'.

I am trying to use this method: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)

Here is the search documentation I am referring to: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms

Welcome any ideas. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is a Drive Labels API you can find in by going to your GCP project and searching fr it in the library.